# DISCORD AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, discord

So I'm in the process of making a verify bot that distributes roles. He should read this role ID from a serverSetups.json. This is what this .json currently looks like:

```
{
    "1139335633882579027": {
        "mute_role": 1139356364297220167,
        "member_role": 1139338847080165406,
        "invite_link": "https://discord.gg/123"
    },
    "933078112047091753": {
        "mute_role": 937777431975182376,
        "member_role": 937776349001678908,
        "invite_link": "https://discord.gg/123"
    },
    "1028973807240740904": {
        "mute_role": 1139559797268688896,
        "member_role": 1139559797268688896,
        "invite_link": "https://discord.gg/123"
    }
}
```

The bot should capture the guild_id and then look for it in the .json. When it finds one, it sends the verify embed. If the user now presses the button, the bot should find the "member_role" value from the .json together with the guild_id, and then give the user the role with this ID.

Now the problem is that every time I click "Verify!" under the Discord press Embed, an error message appears with this message:

```
2023-08-13 22:38:12 ERROR    discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view <VerifyButton timeout=None children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.primary: 1> url=None disabled=False label='Verify!' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\Tim\OneDrive\Dokumente\Dev\Python_JS\GlobalBot\main.py", line 242, in verify
    user = interaction.user
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'user'
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
class VerifyButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, role_id):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.role_id = role_id
 
    @discord.ui.button(label="Verify!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def verify(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        user = interaction.user
        guild = interaction.guild
 
        role = guild.get_role(self.role_id)
        if role:
            await user.add_roles(role, reason="Button Clicked")
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Verifying successful!", description="Vielen Dank, dass du dich verifiziert hast. Du hast nun vollen Zugriff auf den Server!")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Verifying Error!", description="Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten beim Hinzufügen der Rolle.")
 
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
 
@bot.command()
@commands.check(is_allowed)
async def test(ctx):  
    guild_id = None
 
    if ctx.guild:  # Überprüfe, ob ctx.guild existiert
        guild_id = ctx.guild.id
 
    if str(guild_id) in server_setups:
        setup_data = server_setups[str(guild_id)]
        if 'member_role' in setup_data:
            role_id = setup_data['member_role']
            role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)
            if role:
                view = VerifyButton(role_id)
                await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Wie du dich verifizieren kannst", description="Um Zugriff auf den Server haben zu können, musst du dich verifizieren. Dies ist ganz leicht. Klicke einfach auf den Button unter dieser Nachricht, und schon bist du verifiziert."), view=view)
            else:
                await ctx.send("Rolle nicht gefunden.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Member-Rolle nicht in den Server-Setups gefunden.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Server-Setup wurde nicht gefunden.")
```

I've used other methods many times now, but keep encountering the same error.

I also have the same code again, without the role ID being read from the .json, but already specified, and the error does not appear there, although the same method is used in principle.

This is the other code, without the .json file:

```
class TestMenuButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
 
    @discord.ui.button(label="Verify!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        user = interaction.user
        role_id = 1139338847080165406  # ID der Rolle, die zugewiesen werden soll
 
        role = interaction.guild.get_role(role_id)
        if role:
            await user.add_roles(role, reason="Button Clicked")
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Verifying successfull!", description="Vielen Dank das du dich verifiziert hast. Du hast nun vollen Zugriff auf den Server!")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Verifying Error!", description="An error occurred while granting the role.")
 
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
 
 
@bot.tree.command(name="verify")
@commands.check(is_allowed)
async def buttonmenu(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    view = TestMenuButton()
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=discord.Embed(title="Wie du dich verifizieren kannst", description="Um Zugriff auf den Server haben zu können musst du dich Verifizieren. Dies ist ganz leicht. Klicke einfach auf den Button unter dieseer Nachricht, und schon bist du Verifiziert."), view=view)
```

Does anyone know what could be the reason?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment on this [Pycord issue](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/issues/1073), which appears to be the same problem that you are facing:

> **Your parameters are backwards, `Button` is passed before `Interaction`.**

You should switch the `button` and `interaction` parameters:

```
@discord.ui.button(...)
async def verify(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    ...
```

I assume you are using Pycord and not discord.py (explained below).

---

Note that `discord.py`, the library of which Pycord is a fork, appears to do the opposite, passing `Interaction` before `Button` like you do, as you can see in [this example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/confirm.py).

Comment: Cant follow you right now. I have it like you have it in the example don't I?

Comment: @シBxrcode Sorry for the confusion. The example is from discord.py, but PyCord (which I assume you are using) passes them in the opposite order, with Button before Interaction. I edited the answer with a correct example.